# PyQt4 QLineEdit()

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am trying to make a simple GUI that I want to use in an overall bigger program, but what I am trying to do is use `QlineEdit` in a table and once the `QlineEdit` is changed in the example to anything I can pick up that change and save that change in a list that I will iterate over later.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
table = QtGui.QTableWidget(6,2)

tableItem = QtGui.QLineEdit()
tableItem.setText( "Testing" )
table.setCellWidget(0, 1, tableItem )
```

So in the example I want to be able to change "Testing" to anything, and once that change takes place. I am lost on how to pick up the change I have tried playing around with `textChanged()` but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
table = QtGui.QTableWidget(6,2)

tableItem = QtGui.QLineEdit()
tableItem.setText( "Testing" )

def onTextChanged(text):
    print 'onTextChanged', text
    pass

tableItem.textChanged.connect(onTextChanged)
table.setCellWidget(0, 1, tableItem )
table.show()
app.exec_()
```

btw, I think it's better to arrange the GUI using qt designer...

Comment: This is great... Is there anyway I could just print the final "test word". Like maybe using editfinished(). I am not as much concerned bout each move just the final overall change.

Comment: @Dumbkid_trying the most efficient way is reading the **qt assist**, i find signal `QLineEdit::editingFinished` do that, it says: **This signal is emitted when the Return or Enter key is pressed or the line edit loses focus.**